# Continuous Integration and Deployment: Bots + Testflight Api on Itunes Connect

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, app-store-connect, testflight, xcode-bots

Is there anyway I can send an ipa generated by bots to itunes connect, using testflight api? I know that testflight has an api to upload .ipas but I'm not sure if I can use it with the latest changes on itunes connect and with the integration of testflight on Apple systems.

This is something that I'm currently accomplishing with jenkins + custom distribution channel and a few shell scripts files. I wonder if it is possible to do with = Bots + Triggers + Testflight API + Itunes Connect .

Answer (score 4):

We were looking to do the same thing. I pulled this from Apple's documentation.

> **Does TestFlight Beta Testing offer APIs for build server integration?**
>
> ```
>     No. We don’t offer APIs for build-server integration.
> ```

So as of now... no

Answer (score 4):

found out how . [Fastlane](http://fastlane.tools) this amazing library lets you automate all iOS development process , among its features is the ability to upload to test flight / App Store using scripts that can be plugged on a ci environment.

Comment: Yes, you can use `deliver`, which supports TestFlight deployments using the `deliver testflight` command.